# Terminate GObject.Mainloop() threads together with main

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygobject

I have the following two threads:

```
myThread = threading.Thread(target=sender.mainloop.run, daemon=True)
myThread.start()

myThread2 = threading.Thread(target=receiver.mainloop.run, daemon=True)
myThread2.start()
```

The targets are GObject.Mainloop() methods.
Afterwards my main program is in an infinite loop.

My problem is that when the execution is terminated by CTRL-C, Keyboardexception is raised for both threads, but the main program does not terminate.

Any ideas how could both the main program and the two threads be terminated by CTRL-C?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ctrl-c issues a SIGINT signal, which you can capture in your main thread for a callback. You can then run whatever shutdown code you want in the callback, maybe a `sender/receiver.mainloop.quit()` or something.

```
import threading                                                                                                      
import signal
import sys 

def loop():
  while True:
    pass

def exit(signal, frame):
  sys.exit(0)

myThread = threading.Thread(target=loop)
myThread.daemon = True
myThread.start()

myThread2 = threading.Thread(target=loop)
myThread2.daemon = True
myThread2.start()

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit)

loop()
```